# Clear back stack but keep transition animations

Tags: android, android-intent

My application scenario looks like this :

MainActivity > TaskActivity > TaskActivity > TaskActivity > ... > MainActivity

Each TaskActivity

- launches next one depending on the user content
- is able to go back to MainActivity

Previous activities do **not** need to be kept in back stack. Actually I want them not to be kept, given the fact that a lot of activities can be launched (causing problems of memory consumption = frequent OutOfMemory exception) and I don't allow the user to go back to previous activities.

Here is my TaskActivity :

```
public class TaskActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private void launchNextTask(Task nextTask) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TaskActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(TASK_KEY, nextTask);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

All my activites have transition animations :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

It was working fine until I added the *NEW_TASK* and *CLEAR_TASK* flags in the intent.

So this code is working fine, I can see GC freeing memory each time I launch a TaskActivity, except activity transitions are not working anymore.

**Question is** : Which intent flags could I use to **clear back stack** each time a TaskActivity is launched, and still **keep activity transitions**?

Comment: This line was in the `onCreate()` method of a super class for all my activities. Moving this line right after the `startActivity()` was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no worries. Added it as an answer and deleted the comment since answers shouldn't be put in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
public class TaskActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private void launchNextTask(Task nextTask) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TaskActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(TASK_KEY, nextTask);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }
}
```

And it should fix your issue.

Comment: The question is "Clear back stack but keep transition animations", i'm always getting a white screen in the middle of the animations because the stack is beeing cleared i think